# Как убрать курсор мыши в теме Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На теме установлен эффект следования кругляшка за мышкой. Я хочу убрать этот кругляшок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот сам кругляшок, он следует за мышкой. Мне надо его убрать. В настройках темы не нашёл. Скорей всего что то на уровне файлов нужно это делать

Comment: В секретной теме на секретном сайте? С фотографиями - это к экстрасенсам.

Comment: спс бро, решил проблему